# Python: pass file as input in NetBeans

Tags: python, netbeans

Using Python in `NetBeans` and having some trouble to set up file `arguments` as `input/output`. For instance:

```
import re, sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    for token in re.split("\s+", line.strip()):
        print(token)
```

Command line usage `python splitprog.py < input.txt > output.txt` works great. But in NetBeans the output window just waits, with nothing happening even if one give a file name (tested many combinations).

The `Application Arguments` row in project properties (where one would enter these files for a Java project) doesn’t seem to be used either, as the behaviour is the same regardless of whether there are file names/paths there or not. Is there some trick to get this to work or are file args currently unusable when it comes to Python in NetBeans?

**ADD**: As per suggestion by [@John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705156/python-pass-file-as-input-in-netbeans#33705201), an example solution:

```
import re, sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as infile:
    with open(sys.argv[2], "w") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            for token in re.split("\s+", line.strip()):
                print(token, file = outfile)
```

Argument files are set in NB project properties. In command prompt, the programme is now simply run by `python splitprog.py input.txt output.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
python splitprog.py < input.txt > output.txt
```

You are redirecting `input.txt` to `stdin` of `python`, and `stdout` of `python` to `output.txt`.  You aren't using command line arguments to `splitprog.py` at all.

[NetBeans does not support this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/959390/4323)

Instead, you should pass the filenames as arguments, like this:

```
python splitprog.py input.txt output.txt
```

Then in NetBeans you just set the command line arguments to `input.txt output.txt` and it will work the same as the above command line in the shell.  You'll need to modify your program slightly, perhaps like this:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # ...
```

If you still want to support `stdin` and `stdout`, one convention is to use `-` to mean those standard streams, so you could code your program to support this:

```
python splitprog.py - - < input.txt > output.txt
```

That is, you can write your program to understand `-` as "use the standard stream from the shell", if you need to support the old way of doing things.  Or just default to this behavior if no command line arguments are given.

Comment: Very informative, thank you! I’ve tried to write a code based on one of your solutions and the output is somewhat unexpected. I’ve edited the original question; would you mind checking out the code?

Comment: @Россарх: You used to use `print` and now you're using `write` which does not add newlines.  You can do `print(token, file=outfile)` or `outfile.write(token + '\n')`.